# Принудительно остановить загрузку страницы Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Как можно принудительно остановить загрузку страницы в `Selenium ChromeDriver` - если она бесконечно в режиме загрузки ?

- Были бы интересны варианты как в обычном режиме, так и в `--headles`

Перерыл сотни страниц в интернете и ничего не нашёл, а самому знаний не хватает.

Нашёл вот такую строку:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)Browser).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete");
```

Но судя по всему, она просто возвращает текущий статус, а не устанавливает его.

А вот такая:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)Browser).ExecuteScript("window.stop();");
```

Выдаёт исключение, связанное с таймаутом.

**Как можно остановить и после чего вытащить html код ?**

Answer (score 1):

Можно поставить TimeOut на загрузку страницы, если используется FireFox:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("http.response.timeout", 5)
fp.set_preference("dom.max_script_run_time", 5)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)

driver.get("http://www.google.com/")
```

Вот [тут](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5663/is-it-possible-to-stop-page-loading-on-the-browser-using-selenium-web-driver) много интересного.

Comment: нужно решение для Chrome, про FF в курсе.

Comment: По той ссылке, кстати, есть решение и для Chrome.

Comment: Какое ? Перепробовал вроде все , но не работает.